# Codeigniter blog comment id not referencing post id

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have two tables in my database called blog_articles and blog_comments. I have added a comment system to my blog following a tutorial that uses Javascript and Ajax to load the comments into the page. The issue is with tying the comments to the individual blog posts. The comments that load into the page are not related to the blog post and are visible to all other posts.

Looking into the blog_comments table after creating a comment the cmt_article_id field show's 0. I assume it should be reading or referencing the article_id number in the blog_articles table.

Thanks in advance.

Database Tables Sql:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog_comments` (
`comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`emailid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`comment` text NOT NULL,
`time` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`cmt_article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`),
KEY `cmt_article_id` (`cmt_article_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog_articles` (
`article_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`article_body` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

Controller blog.php

```
function display_comments() {

    $data['query'] = $this->mdl_blog_comments->get_article();
    $data['comments'] = $this->mdl_blog_comments->get_comments();
    $this->load->view('blog/single_post', $data);
}
function insert_comments() {
    $insertinfo = $this->mdl_blog_comments->insertcomments_article();
    //$data['comments']=$this->mdl_blog_comments->get_latestcomment();
    $data['comments'] = $this->mdl_blog_comments->get_comments();
    echo $this->load->view('blog/commentdisplay', $data);
}
function displaycomments() {
    $data['comments'] = $this->mdl_blog_comments->get_comments();
    echo $this->load->view('blog/commentdisplay', $data);
}
```

Model mdl_blog_comments.php

```
 //insert comments
function insertcomments_article() {
    $this->load->helper('date');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $article_id = $this->input->post('article_id');
    $comment = $this->input->post('comment');
    $datestring = "%Y-%m-%d - %h:%i %a";
    $time = time();
    $date = mdate($datestring, $time);
    $insertcomment = $this->db->insert('blog_comments', array(
               'name' => $name, 
               'emailid' => $email, 
               'comment' => $comment, 
               'time' => $date, 
               'cmt_article_id' => $article_id));
               return $insertcomment;
 }
//retrive comments
function get_comments() {
    $article_id = $this->input->post('article_id');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('blog_comments');
    $this->db->where('cmt_article_id', $article_id);
    return $this->db->get();
}
function get_latestcomment() {
    $article_id = $this->input->post('article_id');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('blog_comments');
    $this->db->where('cmt_article_id', $article_id);
    $this->db->order_by('comment_id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit('1');
    return $this->db->get();
}
```

View single_post.php

```
 <form>
    <!-- html comment form -->
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="form">

 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"  placeholder="First & Last Name" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Comment</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="comment"  name="comment"> </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Comment" class="btn btn-inverse btn-lg">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
     var article_id = $("#article").val();
      $.post('<?php echo base_url();?>blog/displaycomments/', 
         {
         article_id:article_id
       },
            function(data){
                     $("#display_comment").html(data);});
       });

$(function() {
$("#submit").click(function() {

    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    var article_id = $("#article").val();

var dataString ='name='+name+'&email='+email+'&comment='+comment+'   &article_id='+article_id;
if(name=='' || email=='' || comment=='') {

alert('Please Give Valid Details');

} 
else {

$("#display_comment").fadeIn(100).html('<img src="<?php echo    base_url();?>uploads/ajax-loader.gif" />Loading Comment...');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>blog/insert_comments/",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,

success: function(data){

$("#display_comment").html(data);
$("#display_comment").fadeIn(slow);
}
});
}return false;

}); });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us the HTML form?

Comment: Hi Craig, html form added

Comment: I think you're missing a hidden input, with the articles ID. Both your JS and PHP are looking for an input called "artice"

Comment: Hi Craig, could you elaborate, I know when I was going through the tutorial the sql for blog_articles had 'artice_id' mentioned but I corrected it assuming it was a typo for article_id.

Comment: The second line of your JS is; `var article_id = $("#article").val();` #article doesn't exists in your form.

Comment: added a hidden input field to the form with an id of article but did not affect the database table. Checking the tutorial again what i am looking for might have been beyond the scope of it. His tutorial for the view page seems to loop out the posts and puts the comment box below it.